# Using class as enum-like, or with a specific value

Tags: c++

I would like my function to accept a compression-level (which can take values 0..9). I want the user to be able to set the level manually `Compression(7)` or use some defaults like `Compression::High`, `Compression::Medium`.

I thought of the following:

```cpp
class Compression {
public:
    Compression(size_t level) : m_level(level) {};
    static const Compression Medium;
    static const Compression High;
    size_t get() const { return m_level; };
private:
    size_t m_level;
};

const Compression Compression::High{9};
const Compression Compression::Medium{5};
```

The problem is that I am developing a **header-only library**, and doing this leads to "multiple definitions of 'Compression::High' and 'Compression::Medium". How can this be solved?

---

*Edit*

Challenges:

- I only want to have *one* function overload `foo(Compression)` that acts on the `Compression` option (`foo(size_t)` is already in use for something else).
- I'm stuck to C++11 (maybe C++14, but not higher).

Comment: Try declaring them `constexpr`. You may need to declare the constructor `constexpr` too.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks, but sadly I would like to ask you to be a bit more verbose...

Comment: as your constructor is not explicit you could simply use `static const size_t High = 9;` in the class definition

Comment: on the other hand having the constructor not explicit to some extend defeats the purpose of using a type instead of a bare `size_t`

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks! That would have indeed been easiest by that would ruin the overload resolution of the function where I'm using `Compression` as options. I need `Compression::High` to act as a `Compression` instance.

Comment: why would it ruin overload resolution? Do you really need to distinguish between `size_t` and `Compression` ? (if yes I would suggest to make the constructor explicit to avoid confusions)

Comment: not sure if there is a misunderstanding. If you have a function `foo(Compression)` then passing a `size_t` is already fine, only if you have another overload `foo(size_t)` it will be a problem

Comment: @idclev463035818 Indeed, I already have a `size_t` overload. So I really want the one overload `foo(Compression)`

Comment: sorry, I am more confused than before. In the quesiton you write "I only want to have one function overload foo(Compression).", but if you have only that one overload then you can pass it a `size_t`, only if you have that **and** a `foo(size_t)` you need to distinguish between `size_t` and `Compression`. Anyhow, sorry for going a bit offtopic ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sorry for confusing you. You are right. But since I want to have `foo(size_t)` have a different meaning I really can allow only the one overload `foo(Compression)` for this functionality.  In to solution I proposed, passing `foo(Compression::High)` takes the `foo(Compression)` overload. But in your suggestion is would take the 'wrong' `foo(size_t)` overload.

Comment: so you want to have both, not "only one overload".

Comment: btw you have a typo, you define `High` twice

Answer (score 4):

GCC version 9.3.0 accepts that code (C++17):

```
inline const Compression Compression::High{9};
inline const Compression Compression::Medium{5};
```

Please note the `inline` word.

Comment: But this will *only* work if the compiler conforms to the C++17 standard (or later).

Comment: This is indeed a good solution, thanks! However, I'm also looking for a C++11 solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not the nicest, but as a last resort you could use static functions that return the desired instance:

```
class Compression {
public:
    Compression(size_t level) : m_level(level) {};
    static Compression Medium() { return 3; }
    static Compression High() { return 5;}

    size_t get() const { return m_level; };
private:
    size_t m_level;
};
```

Using it would require additional `()`:

```
foo( Compression::High() );
```

PS: If you want to distinguish between `size_t` and `Compression` I would suggest to make the constructor explicit to avoid potential confusion. One thing that can go wrong is that you forgot to provide a `bar(size_t)` overload and this:

```
size_t x = 3;
bar(x);
```

will unexpectedly and silently call the `bar(Compression)` overload.

Comment: Thanks, that is not a bad idea! Correct me if I'm wrong but it would mean that one would have to use `foo(Compression::High())` and not `foo(Compression::High)` (no parentheses).

Comment: @TomdeGeus yes, added a line